# Development environments for google-chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, development-environment

Currently I am coding my google-chrome-extensions using a combination of notepad and the chrome console. I am 100% sure that there is a better way of programming these extensions. What environments are people using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your preferred IDE (eg. NetBeans) and Google Chrome (you have to test on something, right?).

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Notepad++ which works beautifully.

You might consider trying the [crossrider beta](http://crossrider.com/beta) to build cross-browser extensions. I've found the experience on Chrome superb so far.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check:

1. NetBean 7.0 (They have a great version for web development that let you write HTML,CSS and JS with all the great code sniff/highlight/complete stuff)
2. Eclipse got some good version for web dev (PDT and others).
3. Notepad++ , UltraEdit, TextPad or any other good editor you like.

As for the debug, profile and test mode - you have the developers tool in Chrome that are excellent. You might want to check out this short video that give lots of useful tips:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nOEw9iiopwI

Good luck!

Comment: What's the Project I need to create to start developping with NetBeans? I figured the closest would be Java Web, but that's asking for an engine to run. I could just ask a new quesion proper, I guess.

Comment: Yep, a new question will be the best here.